# Update text field into movie clip from main timeline code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working in a project for basketball. I have an issue, all my code works great if all my components are in the main timeline.

But as soon as I convert the text fields into a movie clip so I can animate and apply alpha value, all stops working.

what am I doing wrong ? The only solution that I could think of is writing the result of my countdown into the text field in the movie clip, but it didn't work as well.

this is my code.

```
function onTimer ( ev:TimerEvent ) : void {
timeRemaining--;
if (timeRemaining < 0) {
    timeRemaining = 0;
    loseGame();
}
else 
    showTime.text = formatTimeRemaining ();
    var miReloj:MovieClip;
    var titulo_txt:TextField = new TextField();
    titulo_txt.text = formatTimeRemaining ();
    addChild(miReloj);
    miReloj.addChild(titulo_txt);
    // miReloj.addChild(showTime1.text);
     //miReloj.showTime1.text = formatTimeRemaining ();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: No se puede acceder a una propiedad o a un método de una referencia a un objeto nulo. / You can not access a property to a method of a reference to a null object.
 at MethodInfo-142()
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Answer (score 0):

There's never a value being assigned to `miReloj`, that's why it's `null`

```
var miReloj:MovieClip;                      // no assignment here
var titulo_txt:TextField = new TextField();
titulo_txt.text = formatTimeRemaining ();
addChild(miReloj);                          // miReloj is still null here
miReloj.addChild(titulo_txt);               // cannot call method on null
```

> But as soon as I convert the text fields into a movie clip

That's impossible. From your code it looks like what you actually want to do is to add the `TextField` object to a container. There's no need to use a `MovieClip` for that, simply create a `Sprite` object:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();        // create container
var title:TextField = new TextField();
title.text = formatTimeRemaining();
addChild(container);                        // add container
container.addChild(title);                  // add title to container
```

**Always use English for all your programming.** Don't mix other languages into it. It becomes a pain to read your code and decreases the number of people that can help you if you have problems with your code.

Comment: With this sugestion you make, there is no more compilation error, but i dont know how to handle that text field graphically. Im ussing that code to make a template in flash and export it in swf. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @epxela I think you can add your `TextField` into your `MovieClip`, Then you can animate and apply alpha value on the `MovieClip`, with `addChild` Function.

Comment: I im looking for a way to write the coundown into the movieclip so i can animate the results i will test your suggestion. @suzuiyue thanks.

Comment: @epxela: please do not ask new questions in the comments. If you want to know how to create a template or how to animate it, please ask a new separate question.